# Cygwin Mingw (C) can't find openssl

Tags: openssl, cygwin, mingw

```
src/tls_openssl.c:25:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/ssl.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:1643: src/libstrophe_la-tls_openssl.lo] Error 1
```

I'm getting this error in cygwin when compiling with make and gcc. What do I have to do to get it to compile with openssl?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the package that contains the needed headers.
`cygcheck` is your friend to find it

```
cygcheck -p openssl/ssl.h
Found 14 matches for openssl/ssl.h
..
libssl-devel-1.1.1l-2 - libssl-devel: A general purpose cryptography toolkit wit
h TLS implementation (development)
...
mingw64-x86_64-openssl-1.0.2u+za-1 - mingw64-x86_64-openssl: OpenSSL encryption
library for Win64 toolchain
...
```

so install `libssl-devel` for Cygwin build or `mingw64-x86_64-openssl` for Mingw build